# What would be the fastest method to test for primality in Java?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, primes

I am trying to find the fastest way to check whether a given number is prime or not (in Java). Below are several primality testing methods I came up with. Is there any better way than the second implementation(isPrime2)?

```
public class Prime {
    public static boolean isPrime1(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean isPrime2(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i = i + 2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public class PrimeTest {
    public PrimeTest() {
    }
 
    @Test
    public void testIsPrime() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
 
        Prime prime = new Prime();
        TreeMap<Long, String> methodMap = new TreeMap<Long, String>();
 
        for (Method method : Prime.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
 
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 
            int primeCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                if ((Boolean) method.invoke(prime, i)) {
                    primeCount++;
                }
            }
 
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 
            Assert.assertEquals(method.getName() + " failed ", 78498, primeCount);
            methodMap.put(endTime - startTime, method.getName());
        }
 
 
        for (Entry<Long, String> entry : methodMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " " + entry.getKey() + " Milli seconds ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to know that the number is 100% prime, your solution is the best.

Comment: I think your solution will do fine. You might hash the results so you only need to 'calculate' it once.

Why do you use reflection for executing a test btw?

Comment: @Stefan Hendriks add a method to the class , fire the test and you will get the sorted result ( i am very lazy).

Comment: The tricks needed to achieve speed usually sacrifices elegancy.

Comment: JUnit @Test annotation FTW ;)

Comment: It's not the fastest, it computes repeatedly `Math.sqrt(n)` and I think the compiler can't optimize it away. Using `n&1` instead of`n%2` would be a simple improvement.

Comment: @maaartinus I read on the USACO training program's tutorials that: "Some zealous optimizing coders like to change `a/4 to '(a>>2)'` in order to save time... Modern compilers know all about this and perform such substitutions automatically, thus leaving the better programmer to write a/4 when that is what's meant."  Just food for thought.

Comment: @SimonT: The problem is that `a/4` is not the same as `a>>2` because of the negative numbers rounding up instead of down. Unless the compiler can prove `a>=0`, it has to generate a rather complicated expression in order to avoid the division (still an improvement, but something like 3 cycles instead of a single instruction).

Comment: What do you need this for? How big are your numbers (how many bits)? How many numbers from what range do you need to test?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
boolean isPrime(long n) {
    if(n < 2) return false;
    if(n == 2 || n == 3) return true;
    if(n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false;
    long sqrtN = (long)Math.sqrt(n)+1;
    for(long i = 6L; i <= sqrtN; i += 6) {
        if(n%(i-1) == 0 || n%(i+1) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and [`BigInteger's isProbablePrime(...)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime%28int%29) is valid for all 32 bit `int`'s.

**EDIT**

Note that `isProbablePrime(certainty)` does not always produce the correct answer. When the certainty is on the low side, it produces false positives, as @dimo414 mentioned in the comments.

Unfortunately, I could not find the source that claimed `isProbablePrime(certainty)` is valid for all (32-bit) `int`'s (given enough certainty!).

So I performed a couple of tests. I created a `BitSet` of size `Integer.MAX_VALUE/2` representing all uneven numbers and used a prime sieve to find all primes in the range `1..Integer.MAX_VALUE`. I then looped from `i=1..Integer.MAX_VALUE` to test that every `new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i)).isProbablePrime(certainty) == isPrime(i)`.

For certainty 5 and 10, `isProbablePrime(...)` produced false positives along the line. But with `isProbablePrime(15)`, no test failed.

Here's my test rig:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.BitSet;

public class Main {

    static BitSet primes;

    static boolean isPrime(int p) {
        return p > 0 && (p == 2 || (p%2 != 0 && primes.get(p/2)));
    }

    static void generatePrimesUpTo(int n) {
        primes = new BitSet(n/2);

        for(int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
            primes.set(i, true);
        }

        primes.set(0, false);
        int stop = (int)Math.sqrt(n) + 1;
        int percentageDone = 0, previousPercentageDone = 0;
        System.out.println("generating primes...");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int i = 0; i <= stop; i++) {
            previousPercentageDone = percentageDone;
            percentageDone = (int)((i + 1.0) / (stop / 100.0));

            if(percentageDone <= 100 && percentageDone != previousPercentageDone) {
                System.out.println(percentageDone + "%");
            }

            if(primes.get(i)) {
                int number = (i * 2) + 1;

                for(int p = number * 2; p < n; p += number) {
                    if(p < 0) break; // overflow
                    if(p%2 == 0) continue;
                    primes.set(p/2, false);
                }
            }
        }
        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("finished generating primes ~" + (elapsed/1000) + " seconds");
    }

    private static void test(final int certainty, final int n) {
        int percentageDone = 0, previousPercentageDone = 0;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("testing isProbablePrime(" + certainty + ") from 1 to " + n);
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            previousPercentageDone = percentageDone;
            percentageDone = (int)((i + 1.0) / (n / 100.0));
            if(percentageDone <= 100 && percentageDone != previousPercentageDone) {
                System.out.println(percentageDone + "%");
            }
            BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i));
            boolean bigIntSays = bigInt.isProbablePrime(certainty);
            if(isPrime(i) != bigIntSays) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: isProbablePrime(" + certainty + ") returns "
                    + bigIntSays + " for i=" + i + " while it " + (isPrime(i) ? "is" : "isn't" ) +
                    " a prime");
                return;
            }
        }
        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("finished testing in ~" + ((elapsed/1000)/60) +
                " minutes, no false positive or false negative found for isProbablePrime(" + certainty + ")");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int certainty = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int n = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        generatePrimesUpTo(n);
        test(certainty, n);
    }
}
```

which I ran by doing:

```
java -Xmx1024m -cp . Main 15
```

The generating of the primes took ~30 sec on my machine. And the actual test of all `i` in `1..Integer.MAX_VALUE` took around 2 hours and 15 minutes.

Comment: isPrime3 failed  expected:<78498> but was:<78618>

Comment: `(long)Math.sqrt(n)` should've been `(long)Math.sqrt(n)+1`

Comment: isPrime3 2213 Milli seconds    
isPrime2 3039 Milli seconds    
isPrime1 6030 Milli seconds    

you beat me

Comment: Do you have a source or evidence for what you say about BigInteger?  What certainty are you using?  I have seen isProbablePrime(1) fail with the number 9, so the implication in your answer that it is /always/ valid is obviously wrong, but at what certainty can you trust that an int /is prime/?  How about long?

Comment: @dimo414, true, I forgot to mention certainty. 25 should be enough, (probably less) but I can't find the reference right now. Will look at this later today.

Comment: Just use certainty > 32 if you are working with 32 bit integers.

Comment: As this is the first result for java isprime search, I think it is important to highlight a flaw in this answer. For every certainty, one could get a wrong answer. This is because isProbablePrime uses a Random instance to select witnesses (and based on the length of the number, even overrides the certainty). Example: http://ideone.com/t3lo9G

Comment: You only need a list of primes up to 16 bits to have 100% certainty dividing any 32bits int by them.

Answer (score 42):

This is the most elegant way:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    return !new String(new char[n]).matches(".?|(..+?)\\1+");
}
```

Java 1.4+. No imports needed.

So short. So beautiful.

Comment: This regex basically does a trial division of a number in unary.  It has been mentioned in Perl many times; you can see it explained on many sites e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329766/ http://www.noulakaz.net/weblog/2007/03/18/a-regular-expression-to-check-for-prime-numbers/ The only difference in Java is 1) `.matches()` matches the entire string, so you don't need `^` and `$`, and 2) instead of repeating `1`s (which is hard in Java), I create a string of all null characters (by creating a string with a new `char` array), and then match them with `.`

Comment: I guess I haven't worked with really complex regex expressions... so to me it just looks like a bunch of random symbols.  What are the '.', '?', and '+' signs doing?  I assume '|' is a bitwise OR right?

Comment: @ghostsoldier23: `.` matches any character. `+` matches 1 or more occurrences of the previous thing. `?` could mean 0 or 1 of the previous thing; when used after `*` or `+` it also means "non-greedy" match. And `|` means OR, so either of the left or right. `\1` is a back-reference, i.e. a repetition of what was matched in the first group. Basically, `..+` serves to match 2 or more characters (`..+?` simply makes it non-greedy); and `(thing above)\\1+` serves to match 2 or more repetitions of the thing above, so it comes out to (number 2 or greater) x (number 2 or greater) (non-prime) # of char

Comment: If "elegant" means "clever and concise," then certainly.

If "elegant" means "readable," I'd say not. I certainly wouldn't want to run across this in code.

Comment: @anula tens of thousands of times slower than the simplest algorithms

Comment: @PaulCantrell The Carmack's [fastest sqrt root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) function is also unreadable, but is the most fastest.

Comment: @anula Not much, I ran this algorithm against the @BartKiers algorithm with a test set of 0 to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and this one lose.

Comment: There is nothing elegant about this.

Comment: The regex is essentially equivalent to division by the positive integer series, which is the `worst case` `naive` solution to figuring out whether a number is prime or not.

Comment: This is slow, cryptic and definitely not elegant.

Answer (score 12):

You took the first step in eliminating all multiples of 2.

However, why did you stop there? you could have eliminated all multiples of 3 except for 3, all multiples of 5 except for 5, etc.

When you follow this reasoning to its conclusion, you get the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: multiples of 3 and 5 and will get elliminated in the first two iteration
of the for loop. Sieve of Eratosthenes method is particularly good for generating a series of primes(IMHO)

Comment: You don't mean powers, you mean multiples.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at the [AKS primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) (and its various optimizations). It is a deterministic primality test that runs in polynomial time.

There is an implementation of the algorithm in Java [from the University of Tuebingen (Germany) here](http://www-ti.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/~reinhard/krypto/AKSTest/AKSeng.html)

Comment: Wikipedia: "While the algorithm is of **immense theoretical importance**, it is **not used in practice**. For 64-bit inputs, the Baillie–PSW is deterministic and runs many orders of magnitude faster. For larger inputs, the performance of the (also unconditionally correct) ECPP and APR tests is far superior to AKS."
That's the practical consequence of omitting the *multiplication constants* in the definition of O(n).

Comment: Even the linked implementation says "Therefor, the AkS test is only of interest with respect to computational complexity theory. Testing 2^13-1 needs roughly 30 min with an efficient implementation."  *30 minutes to test the number 8191*.  That's some seriously slow testing.  There are much faster versions of AKS, but it's still not a good answer to this question.

Comment: The implementation link is apparently dead again, although still around in archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20150717104434/http://www-ti.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de:80/~reinhard/krypto/AKSTest/AKSeng.html

Answer (score 7):

i think this method is best. at least for me-

```
    public static boolean isPrime(int num)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i<= num/i; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return num > 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

A fast test due to Jaeschke (1993) is a deterministic version of the Miller-Rabin test, which has no false positives below 4,759,123,141 and hence can be applied to Java `int`s.

```
// Given a positive number n, find the largest number m such
// that 2^m divides n.
private static int val2(int n) {
  int m = 0;
  if ((n&0xffff) == 0) {
    n >>= 16;
    m += 16;
  }
  if ((n&0xff) == 0) {
    n >>= 8;
    m += 8;
  }
  if ((n&0xf) == 0) {
    n >>= 4;
    m += 4;
  }
  if ((n&0x3) == 0) {
    n >>= 2;
    m += 2;
  }
  if (n > 1) {
    m++;
  }
  return m;
}

// For convenience, handle modular exponentiation via BigInteger.
private static int modPow(int base, int exponent, int m) {
  BigInteger bigB = BigInteger.valueOf(base);
  BigInteger bigE = BigInteger.valueOf(exponent);
  BigInteger bigM = BigInteger.valueOf(m);
  BigInteger bigR = bigB.modPow(bigE, bigM);
  return bigR.intValue();
}

// Basic implementation.
private static boolean isStrongProbablePrime(int n, int base) {
  int s = val2(n-1);
  int d = modPow(base, n>>s, n);
  if (d == 1) {
    return true;
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < s; i++) {
    if (d+1 == n) {
      return true;
    }
    d = d*d % n;
  }
  return d+1 == n;
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
  if ((n&1) == 0) {
    return n == 2;
  }
  if (n < 9) {
    return n > 1;
  }

  return isStrongProbablePrime(n, 2) && isStrongProbablePrime(n, 7) && isStrongProbablePrime(n, 61);
}
```

This doesn't work for `long` variables, but a different test does: the BPSW test has no counterexamples up to 2^64. This basically consists of a 2-strong probable prime test like above followed by a strong Lucas test which is a bit more complicated but not fundamentally different.

Both of these tests are vastly faster than any kind of trial division.

Answer (score 5):

Your algorithm will work well for reasonably small numbers. For big numbers, advanced algorithms should be used (based for example on elliptic curves). Another idea will be to use some "pseuso-primes" test. These will test quickly that a number is a prime, but they aren't 100% accurate. However, they can help you rule out some numbers quicker than with your algorithm.

Finally, although the compiler will probably optimise this for you, you should write:

```
int max =  (int) (Math.sqrt(n) + 1);
for (int i = 3; i <= max; i = i + 2) {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are just trying to find if a number is prime or not it's good enough, but if you're trying to find all primes from 0 to n a better option will be the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

But it will depend on limitations of java on array sizes etc.

Answer (score 4):

There are of course hundreds of primality tests, all with various advantages and disadvantages based on size of number, special forms, factor size, etc.

However, in java I find the most useful one to be this:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(long/int num).isProbablePrime(int certainty);
```

Its already implemented, and is quite fast (I find it takes ~6 seconds for a 1000x1000 matrix filled with longs 0–2^64 and a certainty of 15) and probably better optimized than anything we mortals could come up with.

It uses a version of the [Baillie–PSW primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test), which has no know counterexamples. (though it might use a slightly weaker version of the test, which may err sometimes. maybe)

Answer (score 3):

What you have written is what most common programmers do and which should be sufficient most of the time.

However, if you are after the "best scientific algorithm" there are many variations (with varying levels of certainty) documented http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number.

For example, if you have a 70 digit number JVM's physical limitations can prevent your code from running in which case you can use "Sieves" etc.

Again, like I said if this was a programming question or a general question of usage in software your code should be perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

Dependent on the length of the number you need to test you could precompute a list of prime numbers for small values (n < 10^6), which is used first, if the asked number is within this range. This is of course the fastest way.
Like mentioned in other answers the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is the preferred method to generate such a precomputed list.

If your numbers are larger than this, you can use the primality test of Rabin.
[Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)

Answer (score 1):

**Algorithm Efficiency : O( n^(1/2))  Algorithm**

Note: This sample code below contains count variables and calls to a print function for the purposes of printing the results :

```
import java.util.*;

class Primality{
    private static void printStats(int count, int n, boolean isPrime) {

        System.err.println( "Performed " + count + " checks, determined " + n
        + ( (isPrime) ? " is PRIME." : " is NOT PRIME." ) );
    }
    /**
    *   Improved O( n^(1/2)) ) Algorithm
    *    Checks if n is divisible by 2 or any odd number from 3 to sqrt(n).
    *    The only way to improve on this is to check if n is divisible by 
    *   all KNOWN PRIMES from 2 to sqrt(n).
    *
    *   @param n An integer to be checked for primality.
    *   @return true if n is prime, false if n is not prime.
    **/
    public static boolean primeBest(int n){
        int count = 0;
        // check lower boundaries on primality
        if( n == 2 ){ 
            printStats(++count, n, true);
            return true;
        } // 1 is not prime, even numbers > 2 are not prime
        else if( n == 1 || (n & 1) == 0){
            printStats(++count, n, false);
            return false;
        }

        double sqrtN = Math.sqrt(n);
        // Check for primality using odd numbers from 3 to sqrt(n)
        for(int i = 3; i <= sqrtN; i += 2){
            count++;
            // n is not prime if it is evenly divisible by some 'i' in this range
            if( n % i == 0 ){ 
                printStats(++count, n, false);
                return false;
            }
        }
        // n is prime
        printStats(++count, n, true);
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            primeBest(n);
            System.out.println();
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

When the prime number 2147483647 is entered, it produces the following output:

Performed 23170 checks, determined 2147483647 is PRIME.

Answer (score 0):

tested in a Intel Atom @ 1.60GHz, 2GB RAM, 32-bit Operating System

test result:
largest prime number below Long.MAX_VALUE=9223372036854775807 is 9223372036854775783
elapsed time is 171499 milliseconds or 2 minutes and 51 seconds

```
public class PrimalityTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long current_local_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long long_number = 9223372036854775783L;
        long long_a;
        long long_b;
        if (long_number < 2)
        {
            System.out.println(long_number + " is not a prime number");
        }
        else if (long_number < 4)
        {
            System.out.println(long_number + " is a prime number");
        }
        else if (long_number % 2 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(long_number + " is not a prime number and is divisible by 2");
        }
        else
        {
            long_a = (long) (Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(long_number)));
            terminate_loop:
            {
                for (long_b = 3; long_b <= long_a; long_b += 2)
                {
                    if (long_number % long_b == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println(long_number + " is not a prime number and is divisible by " + long_b);
                        break terminate_loop;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(long_number + " is a prime number");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - current_local_time) + " millisecond/s");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, primes start from 2. 2 and 3 are primes. Prime should not be dividable by 2 or 3. The rest of the primes are in the form of 6k-1 and 6k+1. Note that you should check the numbers up to SQRT(input). This approach is very efficient. I hope it helps.

```
public class Prime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.format("%d is prime: %s.\n", 199, isPrime(199)); // Prime
        System.out.format("%d is prime: %s.\n", 198, isPrime(198)); // Not prime
        System.out.format("%d is prime: %s.\n", 104729, isPrime(104729)); // Prime
        System.out.format("%d is prime: %s.\n", 104727, isPrime(982443529)); // Prime
    }

    /**
     * Tells if a number is prime or not.
     *
     * @param input the input
     * @return If the input is prime or not
     */
    private boolean isPrime(long input) {
    if (input <= 1) return false; // Primes start from 2
    if (input <= 3) return true; // 2 and 3 are primes
    if (input % 2 == 0 || input % 3 == 0) return false; // Not prime if dividable by 2 or 3
    // The rest of the primes are in the shape of 6k-1 and 6k+1
    for (long i = 5; i <= Math.sqrt(input); i += 6) if (input % i == 0 || input % (i + 2) == 0) return false;
    return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, all primes greater than some [Primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial#Definition_for_natural_numbers) integer `C` is of the form `Ck+i` for `i < C` where `i` and `k` are integers and `i` represents the numbers that are coprime to `C`

Here is an example with `C=30`, it should work faster than Bart Kiers answer for `C=6` and you can improve it by computing `C=210`

```
boolean isPrime(long n) {
    if(n < 2){
        return false;
    }
    if(n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 7 || n == 11 || n == 13 || n == 17 || n == 19 || n == 23 || n == 29){
        return true;
    }
    
    long sqrtN = (long) Math.sqrt(n) + 1;
    int[] mods = {1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
    for (long i = 30L; i <= sqrtN; i += 30) {
        for (int mod : mods) {
            if(n % (i + mod) == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might be longer than it needs to be, but should be quite fast.  It is based on the fact that if you use bases 2, 325, 9375, 28178, 450775, 9780504, and 1795265022 the Miller-Rabin algorithm is deterministic up to 2^64.  See: https://miller-rabin.appspot.com/

```
package deterministicmillerrabin;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Determine whether or not a given number is prime using the deterministic
 * Miller Rabin test mentioned at:
 *
 * https://miller-rabin.appspot.com/
 *
 * The algorithm first tests whether or not the number is one of the small
 * primes in the internal list
 *
 * @author bridean
 */

public class DeterministicMillerRabin {

    // Don't make this variable less than 5
    private static final int numInternalPrimes = 1000;
    private static int[] smallprimes = getSmallPrimes(numInternalPrimes);

    private static int[] getSmallPrimes(int num) {
        int[] retarr = new int[num];
        // Store the first 5 primes
        retarr[0] = 2;
        retarr[1] = 3;
        retarr[2] = 5;
        retarr[3] = 7;
        retarr[4] = 11;
        // Alternating between 2 and 4 will eliminate numbers divisible by 2 or 3
        int testnum = 11; // equals 2 mod 3
        int mod3num = 2; // Keeps track of (testnum % 3)
        int loc = 5; // location for the next prime number in array
        while (loc < numInternalPrimes) {
            if (mod3num == 2) {
                testnum += 2;
                mod3num = 1; // Don't need to actually compute testnum % 3
            } else {
                testnum += 4;
                mod3num = 2;
            }
            // Test to see if testnum is prime
            int ts = 0;
            int sq = retarr[ts] * retarr[ts];
            boolean isprime = true;
            // test the elements of retarr up to and including retarr[ts]^2
            while (sq <= testnum) {
                if ((testnum % retarr[ts]) == 0) {
                    isprime = false;
                    // Algorithm finished
                    sq = testnum + 1;
                } else {
                    ts++;
                    sq = retarr[ts] * retarr[ts];
                }
            }
            // Add the number to the array if it's prime
            if (isprime) {
                retarr[loc] = testnum;
                loc++;
            }
        }
        return retarr;
    }

    // These seven bases are good enough to test any number less than 2^64
    private static final BigInteger[] TEST_BASES = {
        BigInteger.valueOf(2),
        BigInteger.valueOf(325),
        BigInteger.valueOf(9375),
        BigInteger.valueOf(28178),
        BigInteger.valueOf(450775),
        BigInteger.valueOf(9780504),
        BigInteger.valueOf(1795265022)
    };

    public static boolean isPrime(BigInteger num) {
        if (num.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) <= 0) {
            return false; // Numbers less than or equal to 1 are not prime
        }

        // Get the last small prime in the internal list
        int tmp = smallprimes.length;
        int lastpr = smallprimes[tmp - 1];

        if (num.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(lastpr)) <= 0) {
            // Do a binary search in the small primes
            int val = num.intValue();
            int low = 0;
            int high = tmp - 1;
            boolean finished = false;
            while (!finished) {
                int test = (int) (low + high) / 2;
                if (smallprimes[test] < val) {
                    low = test;
                }
                if (smallprimes[test] > val) {
                    high = test;
                }
                if (smallprimes[test] == val) {
                    return true;
                }
                if ((high - low) < 2) {
                    return (val == smallprimes[high]);
                }
            }
        }

        // Use deterministic test
        for (BigInteger base : TEST_BASES) {
            if (!millerRabinTest(num, base)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean millerRabinTest(BigInteger num, BigInteger base) {
        // Perform Miller-Rabin primality test with a specific base
        BigInteger numMinusOne = num.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        BigInteger s = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger d = numMinusOne;

        while (d.mod(BigInteger.TWO).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            s = s.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            d = d.divide(BigInteger.TWO);
        }

        BigInteger x = base.modPow(d, num);
        if (x.equals(BigInteger.ONE) || x.equals(numMinusOne)) {
            return true; // Inconclusive result
        }

        for (BigInteger r = BigInteger.ONE; r.compareTo(s) < 0; r = r.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            x = x.modPow(BigInteger.TWO, num);
            if (x.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
                return false; // Definitely composite
            }
            if (x.equals(numMinusOne)) {
                return true; // Inconclusive result
            }
        }

        return false; // Definitely composite
    }

    // Temporary function used for testing
    public static long generateRandomLong(long a, long b) {
        Random random = new Random();
        long randomNumber = a + ((long) (random.nextDouble() * (b - a + 1)));

        return randomNumber;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            long test = generateRandomLong(7, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            BigInteger num = BigInteger.valueOf(test);
            boolean ispr = isPrime(num);
            System.out.println(test + "\t" + ispr);
        }
    }

}
```