# Arcane isPrime method in Java

Tags: java, regex, primes

Consider the following method:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    return ! (new String(new char[n])).matches(".?|(..+?)\\1+");
}
```

I've never been a regular expression guru, so can anyone fully explain how this method actually works? *Furthermore*, is it efficient compared to other possible methods for determining whether an integer is prime?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329766/how-does-this-regular-expression-work

Comment: OK, I take my comment back. It is really strange.

Comment: @NullUserException Oh thanks for the link -- I guess I'll see if anyone can answer the second part of my question then.

Comment: @A.R.S. I highly doubt it's efficient.

Comment: It's only efficient using SLOC as a metric.  It boils down using backtracing to implement the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: So do I, but hey life's full of surprises.

Comment: @Foon - It does _not_ implement the sieve of Eratosthenes. It exhaustively checks every divisor. (E.g., if it fails for 2, it will still try 4.)

Comment: In case anyone doesn't believe it: http://ideone.com/2w2mt

Comment: @TedHopp thanks for correcting me; I had thought as part of the backtracking, it did remember which factors it had already done but apparently not...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, note that this regex applies to numbers represented in a unary counting system, i.e.

```
1       is 1
11      is 2
111     is 3
1111    is 4
11111   is 5
111111  is 6
1111111 is 7
```

and so on. Really, any character can be used (hence the `.`s in the expression), but I'll use "1".

Second, note that this regex matches *composite* (non-prime) numbers; thus negation detects primality.

---

**Explanation:**

The first half of the expression,

```
.?
```

says that the strings "" (0) and "1" (1) are matches, *i.e. not prime* (by definition, [though arguable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Primality_of_one).)

The second half, in simple English, says:

> Match the shortest string whose length is at least 2, for example, "11" (2). Now, see if we can match the entire string by repeating it. Does "1111" (4) match? Does "111111" (6) match? Does "11111111" (8) match? And so on. If not, then try it again for the next shortest string, "111" (3). Etc.

You can now see how, if the original string can't be matched as a *multiple* of its substrings, then by definition, it's prime!

BTW, the non-greedy operator `?` is what makes the "algorithm" start from the shortest and count up.

---

**Efficiency:**

It's interesting, but certainly not efficient, by various arguments, some of which I'll consolidate below:

- As @TeddHopp notes, the well-known sieve-of-Eratosthenes approach would not bother to check multiples of integers such as 4, 6, and 9, having been "visited" already while checking multiples of 2 and 3. Alas, this regex approach exhaustively checks every smaller integer.
- As @PetarMinchev notes, we can "short-circuit" the multiples-checking scheme once we reach the square root of the number. We should be able to because a factor *greater* than the square root must partner with a factor *lesser* than the square root (since otherwise two factors greater than the square root would produce a product greater than the number), and if this greater factor exists, then we should have already encountered (and thus, matched) the lesser factor.
- As @Jesper and @Brian note with concision, from a non-algorithmic perspective, consider how a regular expression would begin by *allocating memory to store the string*, *e.g.* `char[9000]` for 9000. Well, that was easy, wasn't it? ;)
- As @Foon notes, there exist probabilistic methods which may be more efficient for larger numbers, though they may not always be correct (turning up pseudoprimes instead). But also there are deterministic tests that are 100% accurate and far more efficient than sieve-based methods. [Wolfram's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimalityTest.html) has a nice summary.

Comment: +1 for the unary explanation, but it still doesn't really address efficiency.

Comment: @PetarMinchev - Ah, I see that you mentioned the same ``sqrt`` tactic, but I swear I didn't see your solution when I wrote mine. I play a game on the New York City subways where I try to determine whether the 4-digit number of the cart I'm on is prime before I get to my destination, and came across that hint. I'll +1 you when my daily vote limit resets :)

Comment: @Brian It's easy to see how terribly inefficient this is. It starts already with allocating the array `char[n]`. If `n` is large, this will allocate a huge array. So it's a neat, but impractical trick.

Comment: @Jesper Exactly. With a test value of 9,000, it produces a string 9,000 characters long, _then_ tries to run a regular expression on it. These kinds of tricks drive me crazy sometimes. Yeah, it looks cool, but it's not a good solution by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @Brian - So imagine what would happen if we went _OVER 9,000_?!?!

Comment: @acheong87 I wish I could +9000 that :D

Comment: @acheong87 - I like these kind of games. I also check if car numbers are prime sometimes:) Lol, I guess we are nerds;)

Answer (score 5):

The unary characteristics of primes and why this works has already been covered. So here's a test using conventional approaches and this approach:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 2; i < 10000; i++) {
            isPrimeOld(i);
        }
        time = System.nanoTime() - time;
        System.out.println(time + " ns (" + time / 1000000 + " ms)");
        time = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 2; i < 10000; i++) {
            isPrimeRegex(i);
        }
        time = System.nanoTime() - time;
        System.out.println(time + " ns (" + time / 1000000 + " ms)");
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public static boolean isPrimeRegex(int n) {
        return !(new String(new char[n])).matches(".?|(..+?)\\1+");
    }

    public static boolean isPrimeOld(int n) {
        if (n == 2)
            return true;
        if (n < 2)
            return false;
        if ((n & 1) == 0)
            return false;
        int limit = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(n));
        for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This test computes whether or not the number is prime up to 9,999, starting from 2. And here's its output on a relatively powerful server:

```
8537795 ns (8 ms)
30842526146 ns (30842 ms)
Done
```

So it is grossly inefficient once the numbers get large enough. (For up to 999, the regex runs in about 400 ms.) For small numbers, it's fast, but it's still faster to generate the primes up to 9,999 the conventional way than it is to even generate primes up to 99 the old way (23 ms).

Comment: One remark: this doesn't cover probabilistic primes because probabilistic primes are generally used for very large numbers. This algorithm barely operates well on numbers up to 9,999, let alone numbers with dozens of digits, so I've excluded it from analysis.

Comment: Nitpicking, but if `n` is `2`, then the code doesn't work. `if ((n & 1) == 0)` will return `false` before going to the `n == 2` check.

Comment: @PetarMinchev Yeah, I saw that, thanks :) Also, you missed my `i++` instead of `i += 2` ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a really efficient way to check if a number is prime(it checks every divisor).

An efficient way is to check for divisors up to `sqrt(number)`. This is if you want to be certain if a number is prime. Otherwise there are probabilistic primality checks which are faster, but not 100% correct.

Comment: Depends on whether you want to be certain or just reasonably confident... probabilistic primality checks are much more efficient for large #'s