# How to extract the medium letter of a word using only regex

Tags: regex

How to extract the medium letter of a word using only regex
for ex.:

```
"someWord" -> "e" or "W" no sense
"Hello" -> "l"
"Music" -> "s"
"four" -> "o" or "u" no sense
```

Comment: What do you mean by `no sense`?

Comment: And why does it **have** to be regex? This would be so much easier with `substr`.

Comment: In what language are you working?

Comment: I guess "no sense" means "it doesn't matter which".

Comment: If the lenght of the string can be divided by two, anyway the len/2 letter or len/2 + 1 letter will be returned

Comment: I know, this very easy thing to do with other function.But it is strongly recomended to do with regex exp.I wait only for pattern, which use only regex and no other functions

Comment: "In what language are you working?".For me important only the pattern with no function used

Answer (score 0):

#### Id does not make sense to use regex for this kind of task!

As I don't know what environmnet and language you use, I can give you just general scheme:

```
pattern = '^.{' + Int(Length(str)/2) + '}(.)'
```

or

```
pattern = '(?<=^.{' + Int(Length(str)/2) + '}).'
```

Comment: the fact that it does not make sense, does not really make it an invalid question I think. Trying to get to the boundaries of what's possible with regex, might give a deeper understanding of regex for reasonable applications, as well. Just like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12941362/1633117) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12715679/1633117). They are certainly not sensible for productive use, but they teach you a lot about regexes. However, I think this problem is really beyond pure regex, even using `(?R)`.