# Regex - catch repeating numbers (not digits)

Tags: java, regex, numbers, repeat

I'm trying to write a method in Java that checks a String and allows it to only contain numbers and comma. Besides, there can be no repeating numbers.

For instance:

- `11,22,33` - this is ok
- `22,22,33` - this is NOT ok

I've done a first draft of it using a combination of regex and `Set<String>` (below), but was looking for something better, preferably using regex only.

```
public boolean isStringOk(String codes) {
    if(codes.matches("^[0-9,]+$")){ 
        Set<String> nonRepeatingCodes = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        for(String c: codigoRoletas.split(",")){
            if(nonRepeatingCodes.contains(c)){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                nonRepeatingCodes.add(c);
            }
        }
        return true;
     }
    return false;
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible using regex only?

Comment: Using Regex only its not possible. Regex does not keep track of all the actual numbers matched. It just knows that `digit` matched. For a few matches, you can still do. But if you don't know the length of string, then it would be `i don't know how much complex, even if its possible`.

Comment: it might be possible with a regex, but it would be completely cryptic to the next persom coming along. Jamie Zawinski made his comment about regex for reasons just like this.

Comment: Are the sub-ranges of values always the same length? For example, `11,22,33` for length of 2, `111,222,333` for length of 3, etc.

Comment: @RohitJain it **is** possible with regex only. But I completely agree with Jarrod Roberson!

Comment: @m.buettner.. Yeah I saw your solution, and that's why I pointed out, it might be complex, as in your answer.

Comment: @RohitJain it is possible..buettner always makes it possible

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It.. Yeah. I have seen it many times. :)

Comment: I'm sure you could do it with back references, but it would be dog slow, and highly cryptic, as Jarrod Roberson says.  Relevant Brian Kernighan quote: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."

Answer (score 6):

I doubt that it is advisable (as Jarrod Roberson mentioned), since it is hard to understand for any fellow coder on your project. But it is definitely possible with regex only:

```
^(?:(\d+)(?!.*,\1(?!\d)),)*\d+$
```

The double-negative lookahead makes it a bit difficult to understand. But here is an explanation:

```
^                # anchor the regex to the beginning of the string
(?:              # subpattern that matches all numbers, but the last one and all commas
    (\d+)        # capturing group \1, a full number
    (?!          # negative lookahead, that asserts that this number does not occur again
        .*       # consume as much as you want, to look through the whole string
        ,        # match a comma
        \1       # match the number we have already found
        (?!\d)   # make sure that the number has ended (so we don't get false negatives)
    )            # end of lookahead
    ,            # match the comma
)*               # end of subpattern, repeat 0 or more times
\d+              # match the last number
$                # anchor the regex to the beginning of the string
```

Note that this up there is just the general regex, not specific to Java. In Java you need to escape every backslash, otherwise it won't get through to the regex engine:

```
^(?:(\\d+)(?!.*,\\1(?!\\d)),)*\\d+$
```

Answer (score 2):

Be warned that using regular expressions for what's technically a non-regular language can be dangerous, especially for large, non-matching strings. You can introduce exponential time complexity if you're not careful. Also, regular expression engines have to do some back-door tricks that can also slow down the engine.

If you try the other solutions and they give you problems, you can try it this way using a capture group along with the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes to make your code cleaner:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([\\d]+),?");

public static boolean isValid(String str) {
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(str);
    Set<Integer> found = new HashSet<Integer>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (!found.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out there's a difference between regular and other (context-sensitive) languages here.

Comment: Why the direct use for the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes? I believe `String.split()` would achieve the same results which a lesser code and resources footprint. - And why converting to `Integer`? I think it reduces flexibility and adds unnecessary processing due to the conversion operation, while serving no real purpose to the `boolean` results as far as the OP's example goes. (I realize the matcher and this conversion are important if the integer format must be guaranteed, though) --- See [my version of your method](http://pastebin.com/vJEZFHaG), and feel free use at will if you'd like.

Comment: @TheLima All your answer does is reiterate what the OP already knew. He already had the `String.split(",")` solution in his question. As for extra allocation/processing, you're talking microseconds and kilobytes, which screams premature optimization. My code makes sense and is readable, which is [what experts do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015244/example-to-write-optimised-code-by-seeing-compiler-code-of-built-in-classes/13015420#13015420). He wanted something to match numbers, so I made it match numbers. It was intentionally inflexible because code should indicate purpose.

Comment: I really can't see your point as valid. Your code's difference to `String.split()` is as good as the difference between *"Half a dozen"* and *"6"*. There is unnecessary code within, which *reduces clarity* by *increasing noise*. And, nevermind code, while indeed the performance changes scream premature optimization **to the example**, such milliseconds and kilobytes are of non-trivial importance if the code is applied to massive amounts of data; Something that would be unsurprising considering the question's nature. --- I don't see any true reason the changes would be worse rather than better.

Comment: You point about massive data is invalid. If he wants to use regular expressions in the first place, then there isn't going to be "massive amounts of data" because regular expressions are going to inherently be slower than most other methods of verification (like [testing primality](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12716034/646634)). Not to mention the memory concerns in having data that large even using _your_ method. He asked for an alternate solution to using `split`, so I gave him one that was concise and clear instead of telling him what he already knew.

Comment: *Other methods of verification* that would require the `Integer` and thus need the data to be parsed out of it's `String` source, using primarily `regex` (Incl: `split()`), then converted to the proper format, before finally going to the method's function? - Are you sure that would be faster? --- He has asked for an alternative solution ***using regex only***, and I think you did just tell him what he already knew.

Comment: I'm here to exchange ideas and knowledge, but the Italianated text *"your"* regarding my method left clear your comment's purpose is not the same. As such, I won't discuss this anymore. --- I don't know why you have taken such attitude, but if I have offended you in any way, I'm sorry; My intent was purely to improve the code.

Comment: I'm not offended, nor was I trying to be offensive. I was merely emphasizing that even your code can fail with large data sets. I'm here to help the OP, not get into useless Internet arguments, and I was merely defending my position :) That being said, the OP said: "but was looking for something better, preferably using regex only." I'm leaving it up to him to decide what's better, hence my comments about how he should be careful about a regex-only solution. It's also the OP's decision to decide the merit of your critiques. I was simply giving counter-points so he could decide that for himself

Comment: Also note that I was not saying my solution was faster or slower than yours, so to the effect of "Are you sure that would be faster?" No, I'm not sure, nor am I asserting that, just to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the least-ugly regex I could come up with:

```
return codes.matches("^(?:,?(\\d+)(?=(?:,(?!\\1\\b)\\d+)*$))+$");
```

breakdown:

- `,?` consumes the next comma if there is one (i.e., it's not the beginning of the string).
- `(\d+)` captures the next number in group #1
- `(?=(?:,(?!\1\b)\d+)*$)` tries to match the remaining numbers, checking each one to make sure it's not the same as the one that was just captured.

The `\b` after the backreference prevents false positives on strings like `11,111`.  It isn't needed anywhere else, but you can tack one onto each `\d+` if you want, and it might make the regex slightly more efficient.  But if you need to tweak the regex for maximum performance, making all the quantifiers possessive will have more effect:

```
"^(?:,?+(\\d++)(?=(?:,(?!\\1\\b)\\d++)*+$))++$"
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex would do

```
^(?=^\d+(?:,\d+)*$)(?!^.*?((?<=(?:^|,))\d+(?=[,$])).*?\1(?:$|,.*?)).*?$
```

`(?=^\d+(?:,\d+)*$)` checks for valid format like 45 or 55,66,88,33

`(?!^.*?((?<=(?:^|,))\d+(?=[,$])).*?\1(?:$|,.*?))` doesnt match if there are any repeating digits..

`.*?` matches everything provided the above negative lookahead returns true

works [here](http://fiddle.re/6thp)