# Can regex do basic arithmetic?

Tags: regex, math, pcre

This is a relatively simple question. Can PCRE (without extended features such as being able to call the host's functions) do basic arithmetic? That is, can I add, subtract, divide and multiply unary non-negative integers using PCRE? If so, how? (note: I can control both the input, the regex and the replacement string)

Comment: no..you cannot(or _should not_)..period..

Comment: @rock321987 Explain?

Comment: Terrible idea.  Please don't.

Comment: @rock321987: Unary numbers may be a possible encoding to do this in.

Comment: **_The PCRE library is a set of functions that implement regular expression pattern matching using the same syntax and semantics as Perl 5_** .. PCRE or any regex flavor was never meant to do any mathematical operation..Its for matching and _manipulating_ text

Comment: @rock321987: So? This isn't about whether it's a useful thing to do or whether the library is designed to do so. It's about whether it's _possible_.

Comment: The regex alone *(that is only a string description)* isn't really able to do that, but: 1) in a replacement context it's possible to use functions to do what you want, 2) when implemented, pcre can call functions in the pattern itself (but not sure it can be useful in your case).

Comment: In computer science theory, it's **not** possible. There are some engines that have extensions that make it possible; but hey, please.. don't think about it.

Comment: @Joey at some point, you have to use functionality provided by a programming language..PCRE alone will not be able to do it(_till I know_)..if you have any suggestion please go ahead

Comment: @SoniEx2, could we know your use case for wanting to regex to do math?

Comment: @SWLim Just out of sheer curiosity. And it could come in handy for codegolf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. By using unary numbers, that is, the number is just the length of the string. This is similar to how [regexes can check for prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329766/how-does-this-regular-expression-work) (Samples in PowerShell for now because most of this is so basic that every engine should be able to do it.)

### Addition

Replace `$` or `^` with a string of the length to add.

```
'XXXXX' -replace '^', 'XXX' = XXXXXXXX  # 5 + 3
```

### Subtraction

Replace `.{n}$` with `n` being the number to subtract by nothing.

```
'XXXXX' -replace '.{3}$', '' = XX       # 5 - 3
```

### Multiplication

Replace `.` with a string of the length to multiply.

```
'XX' -replace '.', 'XXX' = XXXXXX       # 2 * 3
```

### Division

Replace `\G.{n}(?=(.{n})*$)` with a string of length `1`; with `n` being the number of divide by. The string doesn't change if a replacement isn't possible.

```
'XXXXXX' -replace '\G.{3}(?=(.{3})*$)', 'X' = XX      # 6 / 3
'XXXXXX' -replace '\G.{4}(?=(.{4})*$)', 'X' = XXXXXX  # 6 / 4 (!)
```

That being said, the commenters on the question are correct: You really shouldn't do this if you can help it (curiosity is fine, though).

Comment: This is not really the math OP expects this: *can I add, subtract, divide and multiply numbers using PCRE*. These examples are still string manipulation approaches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I never specified what counts as a number.

Comment: @Joey Any way to make division be floor division? (7/3 = 2, 7/4 = 1, etc)

Comment: @SoniEx2: you can use `(?:(.){n})?(?:.{0,n-1}$)?` with `\1` as replacement.

Comment: @SoniEx2: or better: `(?|(.){n}|().*)` with `\1`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte why not `(?=(.))XXX|X+` with `\1`?