# I made this prime function. Is there a faster or better method?

Tags: java, primes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most Elegant Way to write isPrime in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385909/most-elegant-way-to-write-isprime-in-java)

How do I go about making this faster or better? I made it to solve a project Euler problem then optimized it, but I'm sure it's not the best method

```
public static boolean prime(int number){
    int limit = (int) (1 + Math.sqrt(number) );
    if (number < 1) return false;
    if (number == 2) return true;
    if (number % 2 == 0) return false;

    for(int i= 3; i < limit; i+=2)
        if(number % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect for 1 (1 is not prime, but the function will return true erroneously).

Comment: Was gonna point out the Math.sqrt(number) theoreme thingy but I see you already did that :-). Beyond this, I'd recommend checking out the answers for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453793/which-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-find-prime-numbers) question. Although the question is specifically on C++, it shouldn't be too hard to transfer the logic over to Java (as you probably know, both are C-like). So doing some research on sieves of different kinds would probably be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for its handling of the number `1`, the function looks pretty good. One improvement that can be made is to make use of the fact that all primes greater than `3` are of the form `6k ± 1`.

You can choose to [go even further](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization), but you'll have to balance improved performance with increased code complexity.

Comment: How would you implement that?

Comment: @Frank: Same as OP already does, only increase `i` in steps of `6` rather than `2`, and have two `ifs` instead of one.

Comment: @Frank You could modify your loop: `for (int i = 6; i < limit; i += 6) { int nn = i - 1; int pn = i + 1; // check both pn and nn }`

Comment: This is a simple form of [wheel factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization). It can be improved by using a larger "wheel" than 2 x 3.

Comment: @duskwuff what do you propose...show us some code

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how fancy you want to get.

One easy improvement is to use [wheel factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) -- instead of just trying every odd number (*e.g,* numbers which are not divisible by 2), try only numbers which are not divisible by several small primes. For instance, here's an implementation that checks for divisibility by 2 or 3:

```
for (int i = 6; i < limit; i += 6) {
    if (number % (i + 1) == 0) return false;
    if (number % (i + 5) == 0) return false;
}
```

This only has to do two tests for every six numbers, instead of the 1/2 your code does. You can improve it further by adding additional primes (the wheel on the Wikipedia article tests 8 out of 30), but at the expense of rapidly increasing the code size.

If you don't mind getting your hands dirty with some serious Math, there are crazy number-theory methods like the [Miller-Rabin test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). Note that, using the right set of witnesses, these methods are provably correct for all numbers within a reasonable range (see "Deterministic variants of the test").

Comment: Many of the fancier tests will have a tiny to small margin of error but I believe Miller-Rabin was rather good in that it is pretty much bullet-proof against pseudo-primes and Carmichael numbers. So if accuracy is important, I think Miller-Rabin would be a pretty good bet.

Comment: As I noted, given the right witnesses, Miller-Rabin is error-free within a known range. For instance, testing with witnesses 2, 7, and 61 is sufficient for all 32-bit integers. It only becomes probabilistic if you're using randomized witnesses on large numbers.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but won't the above implementation take `number % (0 + 1)`, get 0, and return composite right out of the gate?

Comment: Whoops - special cases strike again. Start the wheel at 6, not zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
BigInteger.valueOf(x).isProbablePrime(50)
```

That'll probably be quite fast, assuming you're willing to tolerate a 1/1000000000000000 chance of error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Sieve of Eratosthenes 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Doesn't really help if you need to check whether a single number is prime.