# regex in Java, String.matches

Tags: regex

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    return !new String(new char[n]).matches(".?|(..+?)\\1+");
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4515687/revisions

What is this doing in detail?

Is `".?|(..+?)\\1+"` equal to `".?"`  ?

( I'm practising regex from this website http://regex101.com/r/jL7qD4 )

Comment: Did you see the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385909/what-would-be-the-fastest-method-to-test-for-primality-in-java/4515687#comment14255500_4515687)?

Comment: Did you see the explanation on the right side in regex101.com, it has explained in detail.

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so let's break it down:

`.?` optionally matches any single character. So this statement will match the empty string or any single character.

`a|b` in regex-speak is different options - it'll match either `a` or `b`.

The last clause, `(..+?)\\1+`, does the following:

`.` matches any single character.

`.+?` matches one or more characters, non-greedily.

`\\1+` matches the contents of the capture group (the bit in brackets) one or more times.

So, to put it simply, no, `.?|(..+?)\\1+` is not the same as `.?`, but is instead a superset (it will match everything `.?` will, and more).