# Find prime numbers in an array using multithreading

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing

I'm currently trying to modify a sequential prime program I worked on and incorporate multithreading.  I'd like to specify the amount of threads to split the work, and then have each thread run an algorithm to find primes, then display how many primes are in each thread.

The problem seems to be that each thread is running the algorithm on the entire array, it's not splitting the array in the desired threads I specify.  I experimented with some other things, but they pretty much just caused more errors.

As of right now, I'm experimenting on an array of 1000 numbers.  Once I get it working, I would put millions of numbers in the array, but I just wanted to do less numbers first.  There should be 168 prime numbers in the array of 1000. The problem is each thread is returning 168 primes, which is leading me to believe each thread is doing the same thing, not splitting up the work.  My question is, how can I take this program, and get it to split the array and run the algorithm that way?  So 0 to 499 would run the algorithm and display the amount of primes withing thread 0, then 500 to 1000 would run the alg and display how many primes are within that thread.

[image]

Here's my code - Prime.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prime extends Thread {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    static long [] primes = new long [1000];
    static ArrayList<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();


      //int max = num;
   public int count = 0;


   public void run() {
        for (int n = 2; n<=primes.length; n++) {
              boolean prime = true;
                  for (int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
                          if (n%j == 0){
                              prime = false;
                              break;
                                }
                  }

                if (prime){
                        count++;
                        primeList.add(n);

                }

          }
   }
}
```

Worker.java

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Worker {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How Many threads? ");
        int nThreads = scan.nextInt();  // Create variable 'n'  to handle whatever integer the user specifies.  nextInt() is used for the scanner to expect and Int.

        final Prime[] pThreads = new Prime[nThreads];

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i<nThreads; i++){
            pThreads[i] = new Prime();
            pThreads[i].start();

        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
                pThreads[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("Execution time = : "+  elapsedTime);

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");

            int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
            System.out.println("How many Cores this Java Program used: " + cores);



          for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
              System.out.println("Thread " + i + "  Prime count: " + pThreads[i].count); // Display Thread count
         System.out.println("Total prime count: " + Prime.primeList.size()); // Output total amount of primes from the Array List
         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // Display first 100 primes.
            System.out.println(Prime.primeList);

         }

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What is your point here? Are you trying to find primes in array in efficient way or do you want to learn how to make threads in java?

Comment: @SalvadorDali. Clearly not the first one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm voting to close this. I understand the answer to this but it's a *very* long lecture on both writing threadsafe code and how to implement a shared worker pattern in Java. You'll need to find your answers elsewhere.

Comment: Simply calculate a set of start and end indices based on the total number of elements and the number of threads. Give one to each thread to partition the work.

Comment: @SalvadorDali  To make threads in Java.  But I'm supposed to use multithreading on an array of millions of numbers and then output the primes.

Comment: @user3577397 sorry, your response was too slow. I already wrote that this is not a good idea to use threads for this task.

Comment: I appreciate your help, Sal.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that each thread is looping through all values `for (int n = 2; n<=primes.length; n++)`. Note that the values in `primes` are not used, just the length. You may want to try to give `Prime` a constructor that takes the range of numbers that you want to process:

```
public class Prime extends Thread {

    static ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> primeList;
    int start, end;

    public Prime(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    ...

        for (int n = start; n <= end n++) {
```

In the setup, pass a segment to each thread. Also, don't forget to set `Primes.primeList`. Note that `ArrayList` is **not** thead safe in Java, so that having all the threads appending to the same list is a really terrible idea. Use something like [`java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) instead (notice above). E.g., in `Worker`:

```
Prime.primeList = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000); // Guaranteed to be enough
int step = 1000 / nThreads + 1;
for(int i = 0; i<nThreads; i++){
    pThreads[i] = new Prime(i * step, Math.min(1000, (i + 1) * step - 1));
    pThreads[i].start();
}
```

All this will help you patch up your exising code and maybe even get it working. I would highly recommend reading a real tutorial on Java threads as well as finding primes so you understand what you are doing better. A quick SO code fix will not address the fundametal issues in your code.

Comment: Nice that you addressed the part of the problem related to threads +1

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was easier to explain than the sieve of Eratosthenes when I'm brain-dead :) Also, that seemed to be the thing that the OP understood least well. Nice job on explaining the sieve. You should mention that you only need to check up to the square root of `n` BTW.

Comment: Thanks, Mad Scientist.  I tweaked the code with your suggestions.  I still have an output of 168 and 168 from each thread.  Could it be a joining issue?                                                                                                               I realize there are issues with my code.  I'm not a good programmer and it took me a few days to get this with its flaws.  I was hoping I was at least close.  I have no business doing threading, but I sort of have to given the assignment given to me.

Comment: Name-mangling aside, you should check out the basic Oracle tutorial before (or at least while) diving in: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html. It is really quite good and is probably sufficient for what you are trying to do. Also, it should not take that long to read.

Comment: @user3577397 i have tried the above  mentioned  answer it is working fine.i found only one typo in Prime constructor. it should be `int end`

Comment: I have it working pretty well too, I think. It says there are 170 primes, 97 in thread 0 and 73 in thread 1.  I believe there are 168 total within 1000 though.  Probably some slight tweaking is needed.  Nevertheless, this really helped me.  I'll give the tutorials a read.  Thank you

Comment: @Prasad.Developer. Thanks for the catch. Fixed.

Comment: @user3577397. If this answer helped enough, you should probably select it.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I have it working and I modifed and put the array in the main method class so I can ask the user how any numbers they want in the array.   I can find primes fairly easily up to 1million numbers, but when I tried 10 million, it started to take forever to yield results. In fact, it's still going on for over an hour.   1 million numbers took 2 minutes to tell me how many primes were in it, but 10 million hasn't given me results after an hour.  Is that normal, or could there be something wrong with the design of the find prime algorithm?

Comment: @user3577397. A bit of both. Mostly probably the fact that your algorithm is not properly designed. Salvador Dali has more info on that aspect of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood, you have an array of integers `[a1, a2, ..., an]` and you would like to find which of these integers are primes.

You want to do this by giving each thread some subsets of these integers for a verification.

---

If this is the case, than you are doing it in a wrong way. You would be way faster by just finding the maximum of your elements in an array. Then run [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Number_theoretic/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to get all primes in below your biggest number (note that you do not need to divide through all integers, just up to `sqrt(n)`, because the biggest prime can be `sqrt(n)`)

Then run through your array another time time and check whether you answer is in the your map of primes.

**P.S.** the similar idea holds if you want to factorize many numbers.

---

If you want to learn how to do threads in Java, than this is not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Between us, we have both aspects covered. Tutorial needed either way.

Answer (score 1):

I took another approach without thread blocking.  The reason this is possible is that `BigInteger.isProbablePrime()` [is valid for all 32 bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385909/what-would-be-the-fastest-method-to-test-for-primality-in-java).  Here is the code:

Prime.java

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prime extends Thread {
    public int count = 0;
    public int lowerBound;
    public List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void run() {
        for (int n = lowerBound; n <= lowerBound+1000; n++) {
            BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
            if (bi.isProbablePrime(100)){
                count++;
                primeList.add(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Worker.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Worker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("How Many threads? ");
         int nThreads = scan.nextInt();  // Create variable 'n'  to handle whatever integer the user specifies.  nextInt() is used for the scanner to expect and Int.

         final Prime[] pThreads = new Prime[nThreads];
         long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         for(int i = 0; i<nThreads; i++){
             pThreads[i] = new Prime();
             pThreads[i].lowerBound = 2+1000*i;
             pThreads[i].start();
         }

         try {
             for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
                 pThreads[i].join();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         }
         long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
         System.out.println("Execution time = : "+  elapsedTime);
         System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
         int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
         System.out.println("How many Cores this Java Program used: " + cores);
         for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
             System.out.println("Thread " + i + "  Prime count: " + pThreads[i].count); // Display Thread count
         List<Integer> allPrimes = new ArrayList<>();
         for (Prime p : pThreads) {
             allPrimes.addAll(p.primeList);
         }
         System.out.println("Total prime count: " + allPrimes.size()); // Output total amount of primes from the Array List
         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // Display first 100 primes.
             System.out.println(allPrimes.get(i));
     }
 }
```

Result:

```
How Many threads?
2
Execution time = : 35
How many Cores this Java Program used: 12
Thread 0  Prime count: 168
Thread 1  Prime count: 135
Total prime count: 303
...
```